# download multiple tweet with python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy 

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


results = api.search(q="Indian Election")

for result in results:
    print result.text
```

I am able to download only few tweets how can i download 1000 of tweets or keep continously downloading tweet

Answer (score 0):

To search Twitter and stream the results, use a `StreamListener` object:

from: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.

    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['basketball'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://fidlr.org/post/51968189300/fetching-tweets-using-tweepy

You need to create a listener:

```
text = []
class LimitedListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        if data != '':
            text.append(data)
        return True
```